# Difference between `touch file` and `>file`

Tags: io-redirection, touch

Say there is an empty directory and I run the commands `>file1` and `touch file2` while in that directory, but I forget which command created which file.

I don't know what command I ran first and I don't have access to command history.

The files are untampered. Is there a way to tell which file was obtained from `touch` and what file was obtained from redirection?

Comment: I don't think there is a way other than using command history.  I also don't think you should ever really need this information.

Comment: Is this an interview question? Just curious.

Comment: check audit logs if you have it and enabled before, and how you don't have access to command history ?!

Comment: The creation time of both files will maybe be different.

Comment: @Atul Nope. (filler)

Comment: @αғsнιη I do have access to it, but I want look for alternatives.

Comment: @JulesLamur Yeah, my experiments confirm this. But I don't know which command was ran first.

Answer (score 6):

No, there will be no difference in the resulting files.

Comment: @Kevdog777 How's this not an answer?

Comment: Did not mean to critique or request clarification. My answer *is* a precise answer to the actual question, and it was meant as such.

Answer (score 1):

@Hkoof is correct.

Neither `:>` nor `touch` actually create files, they only send requests to the underlying management system which populates the attributes with the information **it** needs, and these are the built-in attributes concerned only with managing the files and their security (who, when, what is allowed to be done etc).

There is no built-in attribute which can be set to record **how** the 'creation process' was started simply because this information has no use in the management of the system. The **how** in file creation is the responsibility of the user.